# Topology induced by the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \sin(x)$ w.r.t. the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$ is not Hausdorff?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\tau$ be the topology induced by the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \sin(x)$ w.r.t. the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\tau = \{f^{-1}[B_r(\sin(x))]\mid r > 0, x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ where $f^{-1}[B_r(\sin(x))] = \{y + 2\pi k\mid k \in \mathbb{Z}, y \in \mathbb{R}, \sin(y) \in B_r(\sin(x))\}$. Then isn't it true that the topological space $(\mathbb{R}, \tau)$ is not Hausdorff? Namely, as the all neighborhoods of a point $x$ are of the form $f^{-1}[B_r(\sin(x))]$, then for $x = 0, \pi$ we have $f^{-1}[B_r(\sin(0))] = f^{-1}[B_r(\sin(\pi))], r > 0$ and thus for $r_1, r_2 > 0:f^{-1}[B_{r_1}(\sin(0))]\cap f^{-1}[B_{r_2}(\sin(\pi))]\neq \varnothing$.

While (I think it is ) not related to the Hausdorffness, isn't it true in this particular case that if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ belongs to the closure of some singleton set $\{a\}$, then also $\pi - x$ belongs to the closure as well?

Comment: Sounds as though it's not even $T_0$, let alone Hausdorff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sin$ is periodic with period $2\pi$, in $(\Bbb R,\tau)$ every neighborhood of $0$ contains $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z}(2\pi n-\varepsilon,2\pi n+\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. And the same occurs with $2\pi$. So, $2\pi$ belongs to every neighborhood of $0$ and $0$ belongs to every neighborhood of $2\pi$.